# Unity 3D anti aliasing not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine, antialiasing

Anti aliasing does not seem to be working with the free version of Unity. I've created a very simple project with a cube, camera and light to demonstrate this.

Anti aliasing is set in the settings:

> Edit->Project Settings->Quality

The project is built as a web player and the resulting cube is very jagged with no anti aliasing.

Here's a link to an image of the quality settings for the project and the cube's jagged lines that's produced in my web browser that I'm using here, it's the same with Chrome and IE:

[image]

And here's a link to the Unity 3D web app itself:

http://moderncoder.byethost15.com/Unity3DCube/

It seems that anti aliasing is available in the free version so what could the story be with this?

Comment: No fullscreen effects are active? What is the AA level you've chosen? Are you sure you've selected an appropriate default quality setting? P.s. dump your images on imgur or something like that and put the links in your post. Then I can insert them for you.

Comment: also make sure you've set the quality settings for Web specifically. In the quality settings it'll have different settings for each export type (web,android,iphone etc)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with links to the images and the web app itself.

Comment: Looks perfectly anti-aliased to me. http://i.imgur.com/HRGFxNB.png Perhaps it's a local hardware issue? Did you try lower multi-sampling settings?

Comment: Yeah, that does look perfectly anti-aliased. I also tried with just 2x multi sampling and still no effect.

Comment: I'm using Intel integrated graphics, although that should work well because it's decent for games and does do anti aliasing in them.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.
I have enabled 'Use DX11' in the Player Settings and issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Quality Settings
SWITCH TO SCRIPTING
Unity allows you to set the level of graphical quality it will attempt to render. Generally speaking, quality comes at the expense of framerate and so it may be best not to aim for the highest quality on mobile devices or older hardware since it will have a detrimental effect on gameplay. The Quality Settings inspector (menu: Edit > Project Settings > Quality) is used to select the quality level in the editor for the chosen device. It is split into two main areas - at the top, there is the following matrix:

Unity lets you assign a name to a given combination of quality options for easy reference. The rows of the matrix let you choose which of the different platforms each quality level will apply to. The Default row at the bottom of the matrix is not a quality level in itself but rather sets the default quality level used for each platform (a green checkbox in a column denotes the level currently chosen for that platform). Unity comes with six quality levels pre-enabled but you can add your own levels using the button below the matrix. You can use the trashcan icon (the rightmost column) to delete an unwanted quality level.

You can click on the name of a quality level to select it for editing, which is done in the panel below the settings matrix:

The quality options you can choose for a quality level are as

Answer (score 0):

Unity lets you assign a name to a given combination of quality options for easy reference. The rows of the matrix let you choose which of the different platforms each quality level will apply to. The Default row at the bottom of the matrix is not a quality level in itself but rather sets the default quality level used for each platform (a green checkbox in a column denotes the level currently chosen for that platform). Unity comes with six quality levels pre-enabled but you can add your own levels using the button below the matrix. You can use the trashcan icon (the rightmost column) to delete an unwanted quality level.